# How to generate a 'collection' form in Symfony, generated by each object within an entity?

Tags: forms, symfony

Having read through the Symfony forms collection/entity types I'm trying to generate a form that only involves these two attributes of an entity (`Person`) but uses all instances of `Person` in the database. The purpose of the form is to provide a activation tickbox for every person on a single page so that multiple status' can be flushed to the database on form submission. Eg, the form should look something like:

```
☑ John Smith
☐ Jane Doe
☑ ...etc
☑ ...etc
```

My attempts below are not working as they just return an empty page, although I can see that `$allpersons` is populated

### My Person entity:

```
class Person
{
 /**
  * @ORM\COLUMN(type="boolean")
  */
 protected $active = true;

  /**
  * @ORM\COLUMN(type="string", length=100)
  */
 protected $fullname ;

 /* ...many other attributes... */
}
```

### My Controller:

```
class DefaultController extends BaseController {
    public function ​activePersonsAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $persons = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')->findAll();

    $form = $this->createForm(AllPersonsType::class, $persons);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && ($form->isValid())) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $persons = $form->getData();

        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $em->persist($person);
        }
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home_user');
    }

    return $this->render('activatePersons.html.twig', array(
        'page_title' => 'Active Persons',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
    }
}
```

### My FormTypes:

```
class AllPersonsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  {
        $builder->add('persons', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ActivatePersonType::class
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person';
    }
}


class ActivatePersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('active',CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('fullname', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Person',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `$persons` collection as form data to `AllPersonsType`, while the type expects that you pass an array with `persons` key and persons collection as value.

```
$form = $this->createForm(AllPersonsType::class, ['persons' => $persons]);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've been tying myself up in knots trying to get it working so really appreciate you giving me the missing piece of the puzzle :)

Comment: The form generates fine but unfortunately I'm unable to submit the form to flush to the database because "EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.". Is there something else I'm missing or can I not pass that `['persons'=>$persons]` array  in after all?

Comment: `$form->getData()` returns the same array structure, so you have to get `persons` key value from the data. If it will not work, try to get data of `persons` field directly `$form->get('persons')->getData()`

Comment: :):):) Thank you - if I could accept the answer twice I would!